# How to use GraphicsQualityOptions on net6.0 framework?

Tags: c#, reference, .net-6.0, aspose.words

I am getting Reference not found error while using GraphicsQualityOptions of Aspose.words. I am using   with net6.0. Any help? Thanks!!

Comment: GraphicsQualityOptions are available only in .NET Framework version of Aspose.Words, that uses GDI+ to deal with graphics. .NET Standard and .NET 6 versions use SkiaSharp and GraphicsQualityOptions are not yet implemented for these versions. The feature request is logged as **WORDSNET-23273**

Comment: GraphicsQualityOptions are available only in .NET Framework version of Aspose.Words, that uses GDI+ to deal with graphics. .NET Standard and .NET 6 versions use SkiaSharp and GraphicsQualityOptions are not yet implemented for these versions. The feature request is logged as **WORDSNET-23273**